# Python - capture ALL tables from an HTML page

Tags: python, html, email, beautifulsoup

I have emails with embedded HTML tables and I have code that uses BeautifulSoup to extract the tables and the data within them, my problem is that sometimes it only succeeds in capturing one table when there are more.

[image: Here's an example email]

The code I normally run on these table is:

```
with open(file_path) as in_f:
    msg = email.message_from_file(in_f)

html_msg = msg.get_payload(1)

body = html_msg.get_payload(decode=True)

html = body.decode()

table = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find("table")
data = [[cell.text.strip() for cell in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.find_all("tr")]
```

But for this email, and some others like it, I only successfully extract the first `Package`. I've tried changing one line to `table = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find_all("table")` but `find_all` doesn't work there.

I'm a novice when it comes to BeautifulSoup so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I tried that and it produces an error: `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you are doing wrong;

if you do

```
table = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find("table")
```

it returns a Tag (ie one element). If instead you do

```
tables = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find_all("table")
```

it returns a ResultSet (basically a list of tables). So far so good! The problem comes in the next line, when you try to treat the ResultSet as if it were a single Tag:

```
... for row in tables.find_all("tr")   # Can't do this!
```

`tables` is not a single element (which has a `.find_all` method), it is a list of elements (which doesn't) - hence the AttributeError. Instead, you have to iterate over each table, like so:

```
tables = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find_all("table")
data = []
for table in tables:     # <-- extra level of iteration!
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        data.append([cell.text.strip() for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That worked flawlessly thanks a ton. I have never received a more clear and thorough explanation either, so thanks for that too. Little things (that are actually big things) like the difference between a Tag and a ResultSet hold me up more often than they should. I always enjoy learning the minute details such as those.

Comment: A quick follow up question if you don't mind: after I capture these tables I turn them into DataFrames to simplify their export to my Oracle database... I've been putting it off but eventually I need to apply that `Package` price to all the Fish-Pound values in the DataFrame, is the simplest most straightforward way to just use RegEx to capture everything after `package` and then append it to a column and have it appear the length of the other columns...?